# Evolution of delegate from 1.0 to 4.0 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I know this is simple question. I am little bit confused with the delegate improvement over the different versions.

I need some clarification here.

1. How the delegate is introduced in .Net 1.0?
2. How it is improved with different versions?
3. What are the benefits over the improvement?

Any link or sample code would be helpful.

I got the link which is explaining other concept over the different version [here.](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/explaning-c-to-my-gf-from-c-10-to-40.html)

Comment: Actually I mean to ask what are new feature/s added to the delegate over different versions?

Answer (score 2):

They are still the same.

In C# 2, there was some optimizations caching created delegates, but that is about it.